# Delete property of generic type

Tags: typescript

I have the following generic function and I want to replace **any** with **< T >**.

```
export const deleteFile = async (item: any, propName: string) => {
  const url = item[propName];
  await deleteFileByUrl(url);
  return omit<any>(item, propName);
};
```

I struggle to define a T which has a [propName]: string property and then return a type T without that property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining a destructure with the `Omit` type, you could do something like:

```
export const deleteProperty = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, id: K): Omit<T, K> => {
    const { [id]: _, ...newState } = obj;
    return newState;
};
```

Comment: Just for reference, if `omit` is to be used, then it will be `await deleteFileByUrl(item[propName]); return omit(item, propName)`